# Looking for a source of data for these specific United States Demographics for People and Businesses

Tags: data, census, united-states, demography

Sorry for if I come across ignorant. I usually hangout over at StackOverflow. I'm a developer and a client has specific demographics needs that I'm not sure where to get. I looked at some Census data but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Example the client wants to know how many 35-39 year old people live in a given 1, 2, 3, 5 mile radius but Census only has 35-44 year old grouping from what I can tell.

Does anyone know who would be a reliable source for all of the following?

It would need to be something I can download and import or even better it has an API I can tap into.

**In Regards to People, distance from a point, 1, 2, 3, 5 miles:
How many..**

- 35-39 Year Olds
- Households with no Children
- 1 Person Living in a Household
- 2 People Living in a Household
- Household Income 75k Higher
- Units In Structure - 1 Attached Unit
- Home Values worth 1 Mill
- Renter Occupied Median Rent amount

**Business Demo Info, distance from a point, 1, 2, 3, 5 miles:
How many..**

- Businesses (Count)
- Other Food Services
- Furniture Stores
- Garden Stores, Bldg Material Stores, Hardware Stores (Can be combined to one number)
- Garden Percent of total business are Transportation,
  Communication, Utilities

Comment: I suspect that this question might be suitable for [opendata.se] SE.

Comment: I suspect you will not be able to obtain all this information from a single source. What you're describing it a market study or market research. There are firms out there that do nothing *but* this service. Some of it, like home values, would come from local assessor records. Some of it might only be available at certain levels in aggregate (such as people per household or income levels). And some of it, like store types, might only be available in assembled, consumable format from a proprietary source. [Esri Demographics](http://www.esri.com/data/esri_data) might be one source.